# SQL. как заменить формат данных

Tags: sql, sqlite

Подскажите, плиз, как заменить формат текстовых данных вида $1,900.00 на числовой  с помощью sql запроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например, `CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE('$1,900.00','$',''),',','') as FLOAT)`

Answer (score -1):

```
private static final int DB_VERSION = 2; 
UPDATE HERE public int getContactsCount() { 
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_SOURCES; SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase(); 
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null); 
int count = cursor.getCount(); cursor.close(); // return count return count;     
} 
private Database db = new Database(this); Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(db.getContactsCount()), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

share meningkatkan jawaban ini
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.